# selection of data from sqlserver database and display it in datagridview code failed to work

Tags: vb.net

am trying to display data from sql database and display it in datagrideview but this code doesn't display column values from the table. the connection is ok and the connection string is working. it does not display any error but it does not work. below is the code am using.

```
Private Sub TabPage4_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim query As String = " SELECT prodt.Name, Types.Type, Types.Kg, Types.Length, Types.Width, Types.Hight, Types.Area FROM prodt,Types WHERE prodt.ProductID=Types.ProductID"
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    Dim adapt As New SqlDataAdapter(cm)
    adapt.Fill(table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub
```

edited: improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t worked with web forms in a while but I’m pretty sure you need to call the Datagridview.DataBind method after setting the data source.

Comment: The DataGridView is a WinForms control and [does not have a DataBind method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...you should use a Dataset instead

```
Private Sub TabPage4_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 Dim query As String = " SELECT prodt.Name, Types.Type, Types.Kg, Types.Length, Types.Width, Types.Hight, Types.Area FROM prodt,Types WHERE prodt.ProductID=Types.ProductID"
Dim adapt As New SqlDataAdapter(query , conn)
Dim ds = new dataset
adapt.Fill(ds," prodt ")
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables (0)
End Sub
```

I Hope it works

Comment: How would using a `DataSet` make any difference?  In your code, it is just a useless container for a single DataTable.

Comment: Have you tried my code atleast once? Use it to know how it makes difference

Answer (score 0):

Try the more modern join syntax

```
SELECT 
prodt.Name, Types.Type, Types.Kg, Types.Length, Types.Width, Types.Hight, Types.Area 
FROM prodt 
INNER JOIN Types 
ON prodt.ProductID = Types.ProductID;
```

If this doesn't work, try adding and SQL tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to first write your SQL statement outside of code. The following can be done in SQL-Server Management Studio or by creating a new text file in your project e.g. test.sql, in this file in the editor connection to the server, write the SQL, run it, validate it works then drop it into code.

Here would be the test SQL (I did this in SQL-Server Management Studio using Product table from Microsoft NorthWind database, added a types table.

```
SELECT  P.ProductID ,
        P.ProductName ,
        T.Hight ,
        T.Width ,
        T.[Length] ,
        T.Area ,
        T.[Type] ,
        T.kg ,
        T.id
FROM    Products AS P
        INNER JOIN [types] AS T ON P.ProductID = T.ProductID;
```

Created a base connection class (taken from another project.

```
Public Class BaseSqlServerConnection
    Protected DatabaseServer As String = "KARENS-PC"
    Protected DefaultCatalog As String = "NorthWindAzure"
    Public ReadOnly Property ConnectionString() As String
        Get
            Return $"Data Source={DatabaseServer};" & 
                   "Initial Catalog={DefaultCatalog};Integrated Security=True"
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Created a simple data class

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class DataOperations
    Inherits BaseSqlServerConnection

    public Function Read As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim selectStatements As String =
                <SQL>
                SELECT  P.ProductID ,
                        P.ProductName ,
                        T.Hight ,
                        T.Width ,
                        T.[Length] ,
                        T.Area ,
                        T.[Type] ,
                        T.kg ,
                        T.id
                FROM    Products AS P
                        INNER JOIN [types] AS T ON P.ProductID = T.ProductID;
                </SQL>.Value

        Using cn As New SqlConnection With 
            {
                .ConnectionString = ConnectionString
            }
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand With 
                {
                    .Connection = cn, 
                    .CommandText = selectStatements
                }
                cn.Open()

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
                dt.Columns("ProductID").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
                dt.Columns("ID").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
            End Using
        End Using

        Return dt

    End Function

End Class
```

Note the use of XML Literal for defining the command text/SQL statement. Also note I included primary keys and hide them via ColumnMapping.

Form code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _bsData As new BindingSource
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ops as New DataOperations
        _bsData.DataSource = ops.Read()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = _bsData
    End Sub
End Class
```

In closing this is a pattern to consider where you can tweak it as you see fit.